# C# right way implement generic method

Tags: c#, generics, coding-style, refactoring, dry

I have some repeated pieces of code. This contradicts with DRY principe. But i don't know how replace this with generic method.

```
class Foo
{
    public bool isFirstAttribHasRightValue;
    public bool isSecondAttribHasRightValue;
    private readonly T1 _firstAttrib;
    private readonly T2 _secondAttrib;

    public HashSet<T1> relatedToFirstAttrib;
    public HashSet<T2> relatedToSecondAttrib;
    ...

    public C()
    { ... }

    public T1 GetFirstAttrib(T3 somevalue)
    {
        return (somevalue != othervalue) || isFirstAttribHasRightValue ? _firstAttrib : default(T1);
    }

    public T2 GetSecondAttrib(T3 somevalue)
    {
        return (somevalue != othervalue) || isSecondAttribHasRightValue ? _secondAttrib : default(T2);
    }

    public ClearRelatedToFirst()
    {
        isFirstAttribHasRightValue = true;
        relatedToFirstAttrib.Clear();
    }

    public ClearRelatedToSecond()
    {
        isSecondAttribHasRightValue = true;
        relatedToSecondAttrib.Clear();
    }
    ...
}
```

I like to replace duplicate methods, like `ClearRelatedToFirst()` and `ClearRelatedToSecond()`, to `ClearRelatedToAttrib<TYPE>()`. And inside that generick method i don't know how to choose which `bool`-variable i need to set or which `hashset` i need to clear.
Same to other duplicate methods. Can you show me, how i can refactor this code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code below:

```
class Attribute<T>
{
    public bool isRightValue;
    public HashSet<T> relatedHashSet;
    private T _value;

    public T GetValue(T3 somevalue)
    {
        return (somevalue != othervalue) || isRightValue ? _value : default(T);
    }

    public Clear()
    {
         isRightValue = true;
         relatedHashSet.Clear();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public Attribute<T1> firstAttribute;
    public Attribute<T2> secondAttribute;
    ...

    public Foo()
    { ... }
    ...
}
```

Comment: If i want return attribute by requested type, how i should implement method? `public Attribute<T> GetAttribute(T){ // what should be there? }`